# Triple boot - change of motherboard

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am (was) running an oldish system with a Gigabyte GA-M61SME-S2 motherboard, an AMD athlon processor and traditional BIOS. I have a triple boot system on a 1TB hard disk: Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.10 and Ubuntu 15.04; all 64 bit. Booting is via GRUB2 on the 14.10 partition. My mother board has now died and my chosen replacement is a Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P which supports UEFI? 
Should the replacement motherboard boot reamlessly, or can I expect boot problems when I install it? If so, are there any work-arounds?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch bios to legacy mode, then the system will probably boot with no problems.

But there is no 100% guarantee that all hardware of the new motherboard id properly supported by linux kernel.

In most cases it should work OK.

Comment: Ubuntu usually adapts pretty well to massive hardware changes. Windows tends to be much more finicky, and may require multiple reboots or even a full re-installation.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it's not a re-install; I was about to get my free upgrade to Win10.  I don't want to go through all those updates again!